# Agenda com SQL (lentidão)

Tags: sql, servidor

Tenho um sistema de gestão comercial e um módulo muito usado é a agenda. A programação (.net+Sql) funcionava muito bem, porém agora a tabela possui cerca de 1M de registros, e está ficando quase impraticável de usar a ferramenta. O nro de usuários simultâneos gira em torno de 70.

As informações:
Banco: SQL Web 2008
Tabela: 1 milhão de registros
Usuários: 70 simultâneos
Servidor: Amazon Ec2 c3.xlarge (4vCPU de 2Ghz, e 8GB RAM)

O select:

```
select pf.prof_id,pf.prof_nome,[dbo].[FN_AGENDA](pf.prof_id,'2016-10-18') from profissionais pf where pf.prof_ativo=1 and pf.prof_unidade=0 order by pf.prof_nome
```

E a função FN_AGENDA:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @concatValues varchar(Max);
SET @concatValues ='';

SELECT @concatValues = @concatValues
+ CAST(ag.agenda_hr_inicio as varchar(5))
+ ';' + CAST(ag.agenda_hr_termino as varchar(5))
+ ';'+ CAST(ag.agenda_id as varchar(12))
+ ';'+ CAST(ag.agenda_status as varchar(2))
+ ';'+ CAST(ag.agenda_comanda as varchar(10))
+ ';'+ CAST(cli.cliente_nome as varchar(28))
+ ';'+ CAST(sv.servico_nome as varchar(30))
+ ';'+ CAST(Coalesce(cm.comanda_status,3) as varchar(1))
+ ';'+ CAST(Coalesce(cm.comanda_codigo,0) as varchar(10))
+ '|'
from agenda ag
inner join clientes cli on (cli.cliente_id=ag.agenda_cliente)
inner join servicos sv on (sv.servico_id=ag.agenda_servico)
left join comandas cm on (cm.comanda_id=ag.agenda_comanda)
where
ag.agenda_profissional = @id_sala and
ag.agenda_data=@data and
ag.agenda_status<>5
;  

RETURN(@concatValues)
END
```

Como disse, tudo ia bem até agora, onde a tabela "agenda" chegou a 1M de registros, e fica muito lento. Nos testes de desempenho, a consulta chega a demorar 1 minuto!

Grande parte disso se deve ao uso da CPU que, em vários momentos, chega a ficar com 100% de uso. A média é de 80%. Sinceramente não acho que o problema seja na Amazon, e também não sei se realmente precisa ampliar o número de vCPU da instância.

O que mais se pode fazer? Mudar a sintaxe? Aumentar o número de vCPU? Abandonar tudo e vender picolé na praia?

Comment: Não consigo te ajudar quanto a Query e a velocidade dela, porém, 80% de uso médio de CPU não é um bom número,o ideal é o processamento nunca bater 100%, independente da otimização nessa tarefa específica, acredito que você deveria considerar melhorar sua capacidade de processamento.

Comment: Sim, no fim das contas terei de fazer isso mesmo, não tem jeito. Uma solução mais sensata seria a alocação do sql em um RDS da Amazon e deixar o EC2 somente para a aplicação, mesmo o IIS consumindo muito pouco dos recursos...

Comment: Sim, daí você configura pra ser auto escalável, como tem uns picos :)